# How to make a program that sends data through the WiFi router

Tags: network-programming, evc

I got a WiFi router connected to my PC.
What I want is to send from another device some data to my PC through the Wi-Fi adapter.
Program on the device is developed using EVC++. The one on PC - on VC++.

EDIT 1:
PC has an IP address.
Another device s IP is set at program execution. I mean WiFi IP address. And then connection to WiFi router is proceeded.

EDIT 2:
What if it uses an ethernet and wifi together?
How should I make a connection through WiFi?

Comment: Is the other device capable of IP networking? Does it have an ip address?

Comment: @kazanaki please refer to the EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiFI is no different to usual Ethernel network.
So you just usually find out IP of other computer (in config/ask user/DNS), establish usual TCP/IP connection and send data on.

Comment: What if I have both WiFi and ethernet?
Now I am triing to use sockets. Hope I am on the right way.

Comment: Yes, that's the right way.

If computer have several NIC it's up to the routing rules to see which interface would be used to pass packets through. Also, you may choose interface to use (usually, via specifying external IP of the interface).